# Detecting ALAuthorizationStatus change iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, alassetslibrary

I'm having an issue where I need to check if the app has access to photos. It prompts the user to decide through the standard privacy pop up. However, it looks like the app doesn't wait for the user to decide and continues on (in no permission mode). So even if the user allows it, it still shows my custom permissions required message box.

```
//force the privacy prompt
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[lib assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] resultBlock:nil failureBlock:nil];

//then check for permission
ALAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

//1.
if(authStatus != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
  //show custom permissions required message box
}
```

Is there some way to get notified regarding the change in permissions and move my code at 1. to that method instead?

Thanks

Jacob

Comment: This is a really old question, but I'm stuck in that same boat. I subscribed to both notifications in the answers below but when I get notified and I call authorizationStatus, it does not bring me an updated status.

Answer (score 5):

I found out after some testing that applicationDidBecomeActive gets called after the photo permissions alert view is dismissed.

I used NSNotificationCenter and was able to capture the authorizationStatus change event.  This is untested below iOS 7.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```